# How to implement 4D Choropleth Map using cesiumjs?

Tags: choropleth, cesium

I want to implement [4D Choropleth Map on cesiumjs](https://cesium.com/blog/categories/userstories/). Anyone know how to do it and show me the code?

[image: The 4D Choropleth map on the 3D Taipei website]
<sub>(source: [cesiumjs.org](https://cesiumjs.org/demos/images/4DChoroplethMap/4D1.jpg))</sub>

[image: The 4D Choropleth map on the 3D Taipei website]
<sub>(source: [cesiumjs.org](https://cesiumjs.org/demos/images/4DChoroplethMap/4D2.jpg))</sub>

[image: The 4D Choropleth map on the 3D Taipei website]
<sub>(source: [cesiumjs.org](https://cesiumjs.org/demos/images/4DChoroplethMap/4D3.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most similar-looking demo is part of the [TopoJson Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html&label=Showcases), you have to click the `Custom styling` button on the toolbar to see it.

Note that you don't need TopoJson to accomplish this, as you can see from the code shown by the above link, it's just using Cesium polygons with `extrudedHeight`.  In this demo, `extrudedHeight` is being set to a constant value, but you'll want to use Cesium's [SampledProperty](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/SampledProperty.html) in place of the constant, so you get a time-varying `extrudedHeight` on each of your polygons.

The polygons and their time-varying heights can be saved into a [CZML file](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/CZML-Guide) and loaded directly by Cesium.